# PayPal - ASP.NET Medium Trust

Tags: security, asp.net

Recently our Web hosting provider moved to a medium trust level for all shared ASP.NET site hosting. As a result, we're having some issues completing transactions via PayPal's SOAP API. Specifically, a SecurityException exception is being thrown with the following stack trace:

```
[SecurityException: Request for the permission of type 'System.Security.Permissions.SecurityPermission, mscorlib, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089' failed.]
   System.Security.CodeAccessSecurityEngine.Check(Object demand, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, Boolean isPermSet) +0
   System.Security.CodeAccessPermission.Demand() +58
   System.Net.ServicePointManager.set_CertificatePolicy(ICertificatePolicy value) +54
   com.paypal.sdk.core.APICallerBase.SetTrustManager() +30
   com.paypal.sdk.core.soap.SOAPAPICaller..ctor() +14
   com.paypal.sdk.services.CallerServices..ctor() +23
...
```

I tracked down the source to the offending method in the PayPal SOAP SDK.

```
/// <summary>
/// To Accept all un-trusted certificate
/// </summary>
private void SetTrustManager()
{
    //This code is added to accept all un-trusted certificate i.e self-signed certificate
    if (Config.Instance.TrustAll)
    {
       //ServicePointManager.CertificatePolicy = TrustAllCertificatePolicy.Instance;
       ServicePointManager.CertificatePolicy = new MyPolicy();                          
    }
} // SetTrustManager
```

Does any know what change(s) need to be made to our project and/or the server to allow the SDK to function in a medium trust environment? Is it a necessity that all un-trusted certificates be accepted?

Comment: i may be wrong, but this might do better on StackOverflow

Comment: i initially posted it there, but my thought was a server admin may have some insight too.

Answer (score 1):

I'm afraid that's not supported, you need to use the classic HTTPS interface integration.
Otherwise if you want to use the SDK by any means, then you have to enable the full trust mode on your server.